# Activate and deactivate an object not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i try to make a fire place were i need to collect wood and use it on fire place but nothing happen, i have used the debug.log to see if the variable are correct receive the changes and its work perfect but the if i have fireonplace variable = 1 then activate the fireplace object the wood its inserted on the variable but the trigger for activate the fire not happen.
This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class enablefire : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject Enable_Disable;
public static int woodonfire = 0;

public void Enable ()
{
    Enable_Disable.SetActive (true);
}
public void Disable()
{
    Enable_Disable.SetActive (false);
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Enable ();
    //Enable_Disable.SetActive (false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (woodonfire >= 1) 
    {
        Enable_Disable.SetActive (true);
    }
    if (woodonfire == 0) 
    {
        Enable_Disable.SetActive (false);
        //Enable_Disable.SetActive (false);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: @Isuka Yes i have debug it with Debug.Log ("wood on fire "+ enablefire.woodonfire); and wen i click the button to use the wood the variable change correct

Comment: @Isuka Yes its a particle system , playonawake i tank so not , how can i change it i am new on c#

Comment: @Isuka i have just see and yes its checked

Comment: @Isuka here is the screen shoot http://imgur.com/a/SBemM

Comment: @Isuka yes it is

Comment: Have you added the script to the fire object which is the Enable_Disable object?

Comment: @RandyR yes i have insert the script on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the name of the game object, as a rule the name has to begin with lowercase, try names like enableDisable;

also you already created a method to enable/disable the GameObject why don't you just change this code...

```
void Update()
{
  if (woodonfire >= 1) 
  {
    Enable();
  } else if (woodonfire == 0) 
  {
    Disable();            
  }

}
```

Comment: I wonder if this was the complete solution, or if he also changed the object where the script was on

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the script onto another object.

Since an inactive gameobject has all its components inactive, the script on it will be inactive too and you won't be able to active the object again. It may be a better option to make the particle system in another object which contains the script. ( You will basicly activate and de-activate your child object (fire) ).

Comment: tanks this did the tric